# How to display the value of an array by the index number?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The user enters 10 numbers. After that, the program asks the user to enter the index number they want to retrieve like the example below.

[image]

How do I ask the user to input an index number and print the array in that specific index number?

This is my code so far

```
public class ArrayElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] Array = new int[10];
        int index;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter 10 elements:");

        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            Array[i] = input.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.print("Enter an index you want to retrieve: ");
        index = input.nextInt();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you writing C/C++ here? Maybe add the relevant tag for your language to make it easier for people to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] Array = new int[10];
        int index;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 10 elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            Array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter an index you want to retrieve: ");
        index = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Element at index "+index+" is "+Array[index]);
    }

Output : Element at index 6 is 42
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the element of a particular index of an array as follows

```
int element = Array[index];
```